# extending global c variable array with swig and python

Tags: python, arrays, global-variables, swig, extend

I have a global variable array in c that I'd like to pull into python. And I'm having difficulties with `varout` typemap:

```
/* example.c */
int foo[] = {0, 1};
```

And here is the very vanilla interface:

```
/* example.i */
%module example
%{     
 extern int foo[2];
%}

%typemap(varout) int foo[] {
  int i;
  //$1, $1_dim0, $1_dim1
  $result = PyList_New($1_dim0);
  for (i = 0; i < $1_dim0; i++) {
    PyObject *o = PyInt_FromLong((double) $1[i]);
    PyList_SetItem($result,i,o);
  }
}

%include "example.c"
```

When I try to build it with the following SConstruct:

```
import distutils.sysconfig
env = Environment(SWIGFLAGS='-python -shadow -Wall'.split(),
                  CPPPATH=[distutils.sysconfig.get_python_inc()],
                  SHLIBPREFIX="")
env.SharedLibrary('_example.so', ['example.c', 'example.i'])
```

`$1_dim0` special variable is not populated, resulting in the following non-compilable code in `example_wrap.c`:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *Swig_var_foo_get(void) {
  PyObject *pyobj = 0;

  {
    int i;
    //foo, , foo_dim1
    pyobj = PyList_New();
    for (i = 0; i < ; i++) {
      PyObject *o = PyInt_FromLong((double) foo[i]);
      PyList_SetItem(pyobj,i,o);
    }
  }
  return pyobj;
}
```

So clearly the typemap match has happened, but dimensionality of array is missing. What am I missing? Hard coding the dimension does works.

**In general, is there any way to extend global `cvar` variables with swig?**

```
$ swig -version
SWIG Version 2.0.4
Compiled with g++ [i686-pc-linux-gnu]
Configured options: +pcre
Please see http://www.swig.org for reporting bugs and further information
```

Comment: I showed how to make your example work, but I'm a little unclear about what you meant with: *"In general, is there any way to extend global cvar variables with swig?"* - is there more to that than just fixing the typemap?

Comment: I was wondering if I can extend the `foo` variable type with `__getitem__()` to make it python scriptable with [].

Comment: Isn't a PyList already subscriptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there with your `varout` typemap. You need to make two minor changes:

1. You need to add the size `ANY` to the `int foo[]` typemap:

   ```
   %typemap(varout) int foo[ANY] {
     int i;
     //$1, $1_dim0, $1_dim1
     $result = PyList_New($1_dim0);
     for (i = 0; i < $1_dim0; i++) {
       PyObject *o = PyInt_FromLong((double) $1[i]);
       PyList_SetItem($result,i,o);
     }
   }
   ```

   This makes sure your typemap is a match for arrays of (any) known size, not just equivalent to `int *foo`.
2. You need to modify example.c to make the size of `foo` clearer. It's legal and correct C as it stands but tricky to deduce the size of the array unless you happen to be a complete C compiler. Changing it to:

   ```
   int foo[2] = {0, 1};
   ```

   is sufficient to make sure that it matches the `varout` typemap.

With those two changes the generated code works as you'd hope:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *Swig_var_foo_get(void) {
  PyObject *pyobj = 0;

  {
    int i;
    //foo, 2, foo_dim1
    pyobj = PyList_New(2);
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      PyObject *o = PyInt_FromLong((double) foo[i]);
      PyList_SetItem(pyobj,i,o);
    }
  }
  return pyobj;
}
```

is what gets generated on my machine with those changes.

Answer (score 0):

For those like me who ponders what to do with arrays of non-simple types -- here is one way to do it:

The non-simple type:

```c
typedef struct {
    int a;
    float b;
} Foo;
```

and a global array:

```c
extern Foo *foov[40];

%typemap(varout) Foo *foov[ANY] {
    int i;
    $result = PyList_New($1_dim0);
    for (i = 0; i < $1_dim0; i++) {
        PyObject *o = SWIG_NewPointerObj($1[i], SWIGTYPE_p_Foo, 0);
        PyList_SetItem($result, i, o);
  }
}
```

Just shared this since it took me forever to find out, and this article helped. Just needed to find out how to allocate the SWIG version of my non-simple type -- found that buried here:

http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn64